# Resend programmatically a WooCommerce customer_on_hold_order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I noticed that the customer on hold order email is not available so i tried to replace the actions with a single action that would send the appropriate email.

This seems to work except for the on-hold status. I dont see what the difference is between the on-hold and processing case other than its not in the `$available_emails` in `class-wc-meta-box-order-actions.php` and I have removed all the others and they still work.

What I am doing wrong? Is it a way to make this possible?

My code is:

```
    function ulmh_resend1( $actions ) {
    $actions['ulmh_resend'] = __( 'Resend Email', 'text_domain' );
    return $actions;
}
function ulmh_resend2( $order ) {
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    $mails = $mailer->get_emails();
    if ($order->has_status( 'on-hold' )) {
    $eml = 'customer_on_hold_order';    
    }elseif ($order->has_status( 'processing' )) {
    $eml = 'customer_processing_order'; 
    }elseif ($order->has_status( 'completed' )) {
    $eml = 'customer_completed_order';  
    } else {
    $eml = "nothing";
    }   
    if ( ! empty( $mails ) ) {
        foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
            if ( $mail->id == eml ) {
               $mail->trigger( $order->id );
            }
         }
    }
}
function ulmh_resend3( $order_emails ) {
    $remove = array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order', 'customer_invoice' );
    $order_emails = array_diff( $order_emails, $remove );
    return $order_emails;
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'ulmh_resend1' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_ulmh_resend', 'ulmh_resend2' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available', 'ulmh_resend3' );
```

Comment: What's the question, specifically? What in your code does / doesn't work?

Comment: Code works fine if the order is in processing or completed status but no email is sent if in on hold status. No messages appear in the debug log, it just looks as if  customer_on_hold_order is not in $mails, but the original email is sent correctly

Comment: Sorry Loic, i must have pressed that by mistake - re-ticked now. all good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have revisited and compacted your code because there where some errors like a typo error in `if ( $mail->id == eml ){` for **`eml`** as a variable name… Also to get the Order ID from the **`WC_Order`** object you should use **`$order->get_id()`** method instead of `$order->id`.

Here is this new functional code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'ulmh_resend1' );
function ulmh_resend1( $actions ) {
    $actions['ulmh_resend'] = __( 'Resend Email', 'text_domain' );
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_ulmh_resend', 'ulmh_resend2' );
function ulmh_resend2( $order ) {
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
    if( empty( $wc_emails ) ) return;

    if ($order->has_status( 'on-hold' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_on_hold_order';
    elseif ($order->has_status( 'processing' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_processing_order';
    elseif ($order->has_status( 'completed' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_completed_order';
    else
        $email_id = "nothing";

    foreach ( $wc_emails as $wc_mail )
        if ( $wc_mail->id == $email_id )
            $wc_mail->trigger( $order->get_id() );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available', 'ulmh_resend3' );
function ulmh_resend3( $order_emails ) {
    $remove = array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order', 'customer_invoice' );
    $order_emails = array_diff( $order_emails, $remove );
    return $order_emails;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> This code is tested in WooCommerce 3+ and **works fine now for on-hold order status email notifications, when resending**

Comment: It was working very perfectly but after updating to woocommerce 3.5.1, only new order emails not being fired. Any idea? Any known bug (I didn't find on woo git)?

Comment: Wow, this sure saved me a _lot_ of work when testing a service that affects more than a dozen emails!  Thanks!